# django booleanfield is None instead of False

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

i' ve a new application with the following model definition:

```
class Sth(models.Model):
    ....
    is_cue = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

. Querying in shell i got the following:

```
Sth.objects.filter().values_list('is_clue', flat=True)
<QuerySet [None, True, None]>
```

. Instead of **False** i can see there **None** .

In previous versions of Django i used to get only **False** and **True** values.

What might cause this change? In the database with older and current versions i can see **0** and **1** in the db.

The versions i' m using are:

```
django: 2.1.7
python: 3.5.3
debian: 9.7
mysql-server: 5.5.9999+default
mariadb: mariadb-server-10.1 10.1.37-0+deb9u1
```

.

Comment: Have you checked if the field is `not nullable` in mariadb?

Comment: Check if you have any null values in the db

Comment: I can see you have some typo here, the variable name is is_cue
and you query 'is_clue' this is a mistake or this is the actual code?

Answer (score 2):

Django Documentation says

> The default value of BooleanField is None when `Field.default` isn’t
>   defined

.
Link is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.BooleanField)
If you want default False then you have to mention it.